# while entering first character, soft keypad push layout up

Tags: android, android-layout

I saw many question where programmer are facing problem when soft keypad display or disappear. But my problem seems unique. I do not face any problem at the time of display or when soft keypad goes. I face problem when user enter first character. At that time i think because of Blue preview of character on top of soft keypad it is pushing my layout little bit up. Can some one tell me how can i get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might not have `adjustResize` set for `windowSoftInputMode` in your activity declaration.  Posting your layout XML and your AndroidManifest would be relevant.